# Identify unknown disc-shaped component - markings include VF10 0471K

Tags: identification, varistor

I am trying to identify this piece, which I believe is a varistor, though I'm not sure. It comes from a Samsung rice cooker. I have attempted numerous google searches on the markings, but I have so far come up empty handed. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: photo of unknown component]

Comment: There's not a lot to differentiate them, but "471K" is very suggestive of a capacitor value (in which case it would be 470pF) and varistors are usually blue.  But I'm making guesses, here.

Comment: What size is it?

Comment: Ok, thanx for the input. Specs are 10 mm diam. and 4 mm thick.

Answer (score 4):

`VF10` matches a type of varistor which is 10mm in diameter, as you reported, and is sold by some companies. For example here is a [datasheet which includes a VF10 series made by AVX](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/AVX%20PDFs/VE,%20VF%20Type%20(P%20Series).pdf).

It has the "UL Recognised" logo (a "backwards UR") at the start of the second line.

`0471` matches a nominal voltage of 470V (e.g. 1mA nominal current at this voltage).

`K` means ±10% tolerance, as usual (see the order code part of the datasheet below for confirmation).

[image: Extract from AVX VE/VF varistor datasheet showing parameters for VF10 471K varistor]

---

[image: Extract from AVX VE/VF varistor datasheet showing order codes]

<sub>Image source: [AVX datasheet, Zinc Oxide Varistors, VE/VF Types for Heavy Duty Applications (“P Series”), pages 3 & 12](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/AVX%20PDFs/VE,%20VF%20Type%20(P%20Series).pdf)</sub>

It's interesting to see the different voltage ratings shown, depending on the varistor type:

- the `VE` series component markings indicate the "maximum operating voltage" (V<sub>rms</sub>), 300V in this case, so the marking is `301`
- whereas the `VF` series component markings indicate the "nominal voltage at 1 mA DC" (V<sub>1mA nominal</sub>), 470V in this case, so the marking is `471`.

[This article](https://www.sunrom.com/p/7d471k-varistor-mov-for-220v-ac) explains that a 470V varistor (i.e. a 300V RMS continuous operating voltage rating) used across a mains supply input, is intended for a mains voltage no higher than 220V. If your varistor was connected across the mains input, and the product was connected to a higher mains voltage, that might cause premature failure.

I have used MOVs in the past, which were that same light-brown colour (although, as commented, blue is a common varistor colour).

What I *can't* do is match every part of the markings on that device e.g. the initial leaning "T"(?) - perhaps a manufacturer's marking.

My conclusion is that because of the points above, this yours is a `VF10 470V` varistor but **not** made by AVX, so it will likely *not* exactly match the `VF10` specification in the AVX datasheet linked above in every way.

Comment: Ok, thanx, great info. This will get me closer to finding a replacement component.

Comment: The device in which this component is installed is indeed a 220V apparatus, and the current in Sweden is 230V. Not a big difference, but never the less, a difference. I will try to source the VF10P10511K variant insted. Thanx again for your input.